# ReactJS: How to pass variable through nested 'anything()(Component)'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*First of all: I don't know how `const result = anything()(Component)` is called, so I didn't find usable info in my search. The title of this post has to get edited...*

But this is my problem:

This is how I add data via react-apollo to my Component:

```
const result = withData(
  graphql(
    gql`
      query Content($id: ID!, $language: String!) {
        article(id: $id) {
          title,
          intro(language: $language)
          }
        }
      }
    `, {
      options: (props) => ({
        variables: {
          id: props.id,
          language: language
        }
      })
    }
  )(Component)
)
```

As you can see, I have to use the variables `$id` and `$language`. Now I need to add i18n support to my component, which I have to do with `translate()(Component)`:

```
const result = translate(['common'], { i18n, wait: process.browser })(
  withData(
  graphql(
    gql`
      query Content($id: ID!, $language: String!) {
        article(id: $id) {
          title,
          intro(language: $language)
          }
        }
      }
    `, {
      options: (props) => ({
        variables: {
          id: props.id,
          language: language
        }
      })
    }
  )(Component)
  )
)
```

The translation is working, but I do get the error `Unhandled (in react-apollo) Error: GraphQL error: Variable "$id" of required type "ID!" was not provided.`

What am I doing wrong as it seems the `id` value doesn't get to the query...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import { compose } from 'react-apollo';

...

export default compose(
  graphql(`query { ... }`),
  translate(['common'], { i18n, wait: process.browser })
)(Component);
```

Comment: With that I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`